# Ruby NoMethodError - Simple search code

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I'm trying to write some simple Ruby code to test the psuedo-code I wrote for an exercise. I encounter the error "linearsort.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method`linearsearch' for main:Object (NoMethodError)".

Basically I just want to search through a sequence of numbers looking for a value v, and if so return the position in the sequence, if not to return nil.

I've reviewed several questions containing the same error however I've found none that I can draw any meaningful lesson from. Please help...

```
class Array
    def linearsearch(a, v)
        0.upto(a.length-1) do |j|
            if a[j] == v
                j
            end
        nil
        end
    end
end

dis = [0,2,5,1,8,9]

print linearsearch(dis, 9)
```

Comment: FYI, you have `nil` in the wrong line.  Put that `end` above it.

Comment: Yea, that makes a big difference. Thanks squiguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke `linearsearch` on an object of type `Array`, not pass the array as an argument. As it stands, you are invoking `linearsearch` on the ruby top level, which is an instance of `Object`, and therefore doesn't have your method defined. Try changing `linearsearch` to be invoked on an object of type `Array`, like so

```
class Array
  def linearsearch(v)
    0.upto(self.length - 1) do |j|
      if self[j] == v
        return j
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

and invoke it like

```
dis.linearsearch(9)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said this is for a project, but is there any reason you're not using the native index method?

```
dis = [0,2,5,1,8,9]
puts dis.index(9) #=> 5
puts dis.index(1) #=> 3
```

Comment: No reason at all, I'm very new to Ruby and it is a little more confusing than Python. Thanks so much.